# Parsing a text file in Julia

Tags: arrays, io, julia

I'm brand new to Julia.  I'm looking for a way to input values from 50 text files into arrays.  The files are named in the form `data-X.dat` where X is an integer 1-50.  The files are in the following format (I have no control over the format):

```
garbage text
comment: words = I1, more words = I2
more garbage text
blah blah   = F1
measurement = F2   F3 text
```

Where `I1` and `I2` are integers and `F1`, `F2`, and `F3` are numbers in decimal form (eg 12.345).  I want to dump the data into arrays such that, for example, the third element of array `i1` is the value of `I1` in file `data-3.dat`.

How would I do this in Julia?  All the examples I have found so far deal with data files parsed by simple delimiters, which is not the case here.

Comment: I think your Fortran example is unnecessary.

Comment: Is the size of the text file small enough that you can just read the whole thing into memory and parse it there by searching for appropriate strings at the start of each line?

Comment: @ColinTBowers Yes, each file is around 1 KB in size, so that should be doable.  This is my first project in Julia, so if you could provide some skeletal code explaining syntax of "searching for appropriate strings" using the example, that would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Read the file in using `fid1 = open("filePath") ; x = readlines(fid1) ; close(fid1)`. When looping over the lines it looks like you could use `contains(line, '=')` to find the appropriate lines, and then some judicious use of `split` should get you there. Not efficient by any means, but it'll get the job done. ps regular expressions are probably the "right" way to solve this problem, but I do get that the initial learning curve for them is precipitous. I tend to avoid them myself, even when I know I should be using them :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the [eachline](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/stdlib/io-network/?highlight=eachline#Base.eachline) iterator on a stream plus [regular expressions](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/manual/strings/#regular-expressions) are what you are looking for.

Comment: and there is always the [wiki](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Introducing_Julia/Working_with_text_files#Line_by_line)

Comment: The regular expressions look promising, but the syntax is way over my level understanding, and playing with it, I seem to only be able to extract one digit at a time.  Could you maybe show me a simple example, say with a string `x = "drag = 1.2345 Newtons"`?  How do I store 1.2345 to some variable not knowing ahead of time exactly how many digits there are before or behind the decimal?

Answer (score 8):

Thanks for the help @ColinTBowers and @AaronSheldon.  This was my first experience with regular expressions, and I made heavy use of the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) page on them.  In case anyone in the future is looking for sample code, this is what I ended up doing:

```
nf = 50                       # number of files
nmbr = r"\-?[0-9]+\.?[0-9]*"  # regex to find an integer or decimal number

i1 = zeros(Int64, nf)
i2 = zeros(i1)
f1 = zeros(Float64, nf)
f2 = zeros(f1)
f3 = zeros(f1)

for X in 1:nf
   file = open("data-$(X).dat")
   line = readlines(file)
   extract(linenum, index=1) = matchall(nmbr, line[linenum])[index]
   i1[X] = parse(Int64, extract(2,1))
   i2[X] = parse(Int64, extract(2,2))
   f1[X] = parse(Float64, extract(4))
   f2[X] = parse(Float64, extract(5,1))
   f3[X] = parse(Float64, extract(5,2))
   close(file)
end
```